# Intermittent sqlalchemy drop_database error (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) must be a member of the role whose process is being terminated

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Have been facing this issue for a while now. Trying to execute my test suite involving db creations, schema creations and deletions using sqlalchemy throws this error:

> (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) must be a member of the role whose process
>   is being terminated

Code in which error is thrown:

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import drop_database
drop_database(TEST_URI)
```

It is confusing and annoying at the same time. Rerunning the test suite might give me a success so there is not a fixed pattern. Wondering if the solution(a hacky one) mentioned [here](https://github.com/Overseas-Student-Living/sqlalchemy-diff/issues/10) is the only way one could escape from this error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: sqlalchemy is probably trying to kill all current connections to the database before dropping it since any active connections would prevent it being dropped. The account you are running under may not be high enough privilege like superuser.

Comment: @Nicarus then why only sometimes it throws an error. I understand there can be some privileges issues but then it should occur every single time

Comment: It would only occur when there are active connections to the database.

Comment: I still can't digest this error. If Postgres is trying to kill/delete the connection may be because they are idle then it should be able to handle multiple requests as well. I just can't think of a reason that it should throw an error like this and breaking my test environment

Comment: You can't drop a database when there are any connections to it. So you have to kill those connections first, then drop the database. If your role does not have privileges to drop the current connections, you will get that error.

Comment: But I am closing the connection first and then removing the database

Comment: You have closed ALL connections? PostgreSQL seems to think you haven't.